# Show that the Cantor set is self-similar

Tags: cantor-set

> Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ be two sets and $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$ a scalar. We define the following operations:
>   $$A+B\triangleq \{a+b \mid a\in A, b\in B\}$$
>   $$\lambda A \triangleq \{\lambda a \mid a\in A \}$$
>   We define a sets sequence $C_0 , C_1 , ... , C_n ,...$:
>   $$C_0=[0,1]\\C_n=\frac{1}{3}C_{n-1}\cup\bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C_{n-1} \bigg)$$
>   And the cantor set is defined: $C=\cap_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i$.
>
> Show that the Cantor set is self-similar in the following sense:
>   $$C=\frac{1}{3}C \cup \bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C\bigg)$$

My approach is to show that $C \subseteq \frac{1}{3}C \cup \bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C\bigg)$ and $\frac{1}{3}C \cup \bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C\bigg) \subseteq C$, thus proving the identity.

I was able to show that $C \subseteq \frac{1}{3}C \cup \bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C\bigg)$, but not the other way. I get stuck right from the start:

Let $c \in\frac{1}{3} C \cup \bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C\bigg)$. Meaning, $c \in \frac{1}{3}C$ or $c \in \bigg(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}C\bigg)$.

Case 1: $c \in\frac{1}{3}C$. So there exists $c'\in C$ s.t. $c=\frac{1}{3}c'$. Why does $c\in C$?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining $C$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo $C$ is the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo Thanks. I'll edit.

Comment: @DHMO I am aware of what the Cantor set is. I am asking the person posting the question what definition they are using.

Comment: The current definition is incorrect.

Comment: @Did how so? that's the definition I have.

Comment: When somebody expresses doubts about something you wrote, *the least one should do is to check what one wrote*... Did you? What is $C_1$, say?

Comment: @Did I did. I don't see what's wrong though.

Comment: @Yes Put $n=1 into your recurrence equation and see what you get.

Comment: Pff... Sorry. Fixed now (I hope...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c \in \dfrac13C$. Then $3c \in C$.

Now, we need to prove that $c \in C$, which is for every $k$, $c \in C_k$.

We know that for every $m$, $3c \in C_m$. Now let $m=k-1$: $3c \in C_{k-1}$.

$C_k = \dfrac13C_{k-1} \cup \left(\dfrac23 + \dfrac13C_{k-1}\right) \supseteq \dfrac13C_{k-1} \ni \dfrac13(3c) = c$.

Therefore, $c \in C$ is proved.

---

A similar method can be used to prove case $2$.